# TimeUUID in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timeuuid

When we use the command

```
set <cloumn-family-name>[timeuuid()][utf8(name)] = utf8(value);
```

It gives me this error

> no appenders could be found please initialize system log4j system
>   properly.

Answer (score 4):

The error/message is not related to TimeUUID. It seems that cassandra is using Log4j as its logging library and it needs a log4j.properties file to configure which messages will be logged etc. just put a simple log4j.properties file in correct place and you may see actual errors/messages printed by cassandra.